# Excel 2007: where to find the option 'Trust access to Visual Basic Project?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007

I tried to run a plugin in Excel 2007, and I got this error message

[image]

Do anyone know how I can access this feature from the 2007 GUI? I am confused by the new interface.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

Office Button->Excel Options(at the bottom)->Trust Center->Trust Center Settings->Macro Settings->Trust Access to the VBA project model

Comment: Ah! Trust center! No wonder I couldn't find the security tab. jesus wtf.

Answer (score 2):

The office menu (one with office logo on it, on left top) -> Excel options -> Trust Center -> Trust Center Settings (button) -> Macro Settings -> Trust access to VBA project object model.

Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: @shahkalpesh: your answer is also correct. Wish I can accept more than one answer. Thanks for your help!